# How to scrape data from an ajax web page using R?

Tags: ajax, r, web-scraping

I would like to extract data from [this](http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/250/Tournaments/12/Seasons/3872/Stages/8462/PlayerStatistics/Europe-UEFA-Champions-League-2013-2014#stage-top-player-stats-summary)  web page using R:

I guess the web page is loaded via server using Ajax or something similar. Moreover I would like to save also the data available on the following pages, the ones that I can see when I press the NEXT button at the bottom of the data table.

Thanks a lot for any tips.
domenico

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be generated using a JavaScript blob. You could look at [rvest](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/), which is an R library for just this problem (web scraping). If that doesn't work, RCUrl's `GetURL` function definitely grabs the script contents (although it's ugly as sin and you'll be wanting to grep it. Mind you, all automatically generated HTML is ugly).